# Unable to debug Asp.net RC1 web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having a issue with debugging the Asp.net 5 MVC application. Whenever I try to debug it gives me error

> "An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application".

I went through the solutions provided in the other threads and nothing worked.

> Environment: ASP.NET 1.0.0-rc1-update1

I tried the following to resolve the issue.

> 1. Closed visual studio, deleted project.lock.json and re-opened the solution.
> 2. Deleted the web.config
> 3. Switched to a new user on the same machine, created a brand new project and ran it.

dnvm latest points to correct version and architecture (x86) as default.

I am not sure what is causing the issue.

PS: I had the same issue last week and ended up in formatting and installing again. Don't want to do this again to solve the issue as it takes lot of time to setup everything.

Any suggestion to solve the issue would be helpful.

Below is my project.json file

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },        
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
    },        
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://localhost:5000"
    },        
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },        
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `dnvm list`output and the `global.json` file. Do you run `VS`as admin ?

Comment: What does appears in the debug toolbar in VS? (try with 'Debug', 'Any CPU' and 'IIS Express')

Comment: Thanks for your reply. dnvm list shows following. 
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win                  
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win                  
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win                  
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win

Comment: Running VS as administrator gave same results. I tried with Debug. Any CPU and IIS Express. Did not work either. 

Global.json:

{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}

Comment: I uninstalled the Asp.Net tools and installed again. Re-installed IIS Express. Problem still exists

Comment: If you set the alias `default` to with the command `dnvm alias default 1.0.0-rc1-update1` are you able to debug ?

Comment: No, it did not work.

Comment: Is your project build without error when you run `dnu build` command ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple console project and debugging it? I would like to determine if this is a DNX or ASP.NET related problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the root cause. Please see below answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Agua and Leonardo for your help. I found out the root cause. Posting here for everyone.

When you set up the project to use SSL, under App URL box, leave the default URL as is i.e. Don't change that to SSL. e.g http://localhost:20008/. For the Launch URL, set up the URL with SSL so that you debug the application.

Simple setting caused me atleast 2 days of delay :-(.

Comment: You should change the question title and mention SSL in your question. It'll help to find your answer